# Is "liberal arts" a unique feature of American higher education?

Tags: united-states, academic-history, liberal-arts-colleges

Liberal arts programs are very common in the US but not in Europe (correct me if I am wrong). As I see here in discussions, the environment of liberal arts colleges is different: for example, student-faculty relationships.

Have such historical liberal arts programs and schools changed the overall higher education in the US or are they just different types of programs.

Are the universities which are not focused on liberal arts influenced by the culture of liberal arts programs/schools?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "liberal arts programs"? Indeed, the term may not be commonly used in Europe, but study programs in the humanities and social sciences certainly are common, so it may just be a matter of terminology.

Comment: @fkraiem as far as I know, liberal arts programs are not simply humanities and social sciences, they are general programs with a wide range of courses from science to sociology. They are not specialized programs, even in social sciences.

Comment: Aren't students in the US required to choose a major at some point? Yes, they are still required to take some courses outside their major, but that is true in Europe as well.

Comment: Part of the issue is that there are a few different things called "liberal arts".  The term can refer to a set of fields of study (humanities, social sciences, etc) though the composition of this set is not really well defined.  It also shows up in the phrase *liberal arts college* (LAC) which is a particular model for an institution of higher education, usually a small private institution.  Despite the names, which are more historical than anything, it is no longer necessarily true that LACs focus mainly on studies in the  "liberal arts"...

Comment: ... and institutions which are not LACs usually also include "liberal arts" among their offerings.  Another notion which you may be conflating is the idea of *general education*, that all students should take some classes in a few core areas, not necessarily related to their major field of study.  Maybe this will help you clarify your question.

Comment: I graduated from a US university with a degree in mathematics, although less than half the courses I took were in mathematics. This is simply inconceivable in most (all?) European systems. The "liberal arts" idea is that a student of any subject should have basic knowledge of many subjects, and therefore must take courses in various areas, not necessarily related to his specialization. European degrees always (so far as I know) are focused on a particular area of study. Breadth might mean a math student is required to take some physics or computer science.

Comment: The question is vague.  To answer the first part, liberal arts are found in many countries.  http://liberalartsalliance.org/members

Comment: @fkraiem "liberal arts" is not synonymous with humanities or social sciences. It is indeed a concept that does not exist in European academia.

Answer (score 12):

It's probably not unique, but practically yes the concept of a "liberal arts" college or education is specific to North America. Some European countries have a form of "liberal arts" curriculum at the high school level (e.g. the German or Swiss *Gymnasium*) where a broad spectrum of "classic" subjects are taught with the purpose of allowing students to join any university education.

But (continental) European universities generally have individual programs for math, philosophy, history, science, etc.

It's actually quite puzzling for people who attended university in Europe to hear their US-educated colleagues say "Yes, I majored in physics and medieval music".

Comment: I recently wrote an answer about things like small liberal arts colleges in Europe: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/187611/how-do-i-find-small-teaching-focused-universities-in-the-european-union/208989#208989

Answer (score -1):

In a short, simple answer: no. Strictly speaking, liberal arts degrees are not *unique* to North America because one can earn them [elsewhere](https://www.exeter.ac.uk/undergraduate/degrees/libarts/liberal/).

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer rather than only posting a link.

Comment: Yes, link-only answers are discouraged because then the answer is only useful as long as the link survives. I've added a few words to expand on what I think your intended meaning is.

Answer (score -5):

Almost all schools possess a form of LA training, even if they do not adapt the title. LA programs are generally rooted in the classics. Therefore, LA training could be nestled under the title of History, Litt, Classics… In the US, a classical edu. is quickly fading. There are only a handful of schools that offer them. Such as St. Johns, Chicago, SBC Undergrads, HMU… In general, the LA and Humanities have been in a decline (although there was a recent bump in applications). Your question about cultural impact: Every university you go to is impacted by the surrounding culture, and will shape the teaching. Since much of LA is rooted in classics, its helps bc the material is static, but ones approach can be entirely different from school to school.

Comment: "Almost all schools possess..." do you mean "schools in the US"?